# Get device location onDemand

Tags: android, gps, geolocation

So there is a lot of talk about getting device location. My need is very particular and I am wondering if there is an exact answer.

- I do not want to track users.
- There is a specific activity in my app that requires location. So when a user go take that specific action, I need to get the location of the device.
- I need the location acquisition to happen very fast
- I want FINE location.

The Android example seems to be about coarse location only https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

And the answers here seem to be about tracking a user.

For my app, the action in question is not frequent at all (maybe once or twice a week), but when the user wants to use that feature, I need the finest current location.

So is my only solution to track the user?

Comment: this my be of some help http://www.andygup.net/how-accurate-is-android-gps-part-2-consuming-real-time-locations/

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you linked specifies:

> The permission you choose determines the accuracy of the location returned by the API

and later

> The precision of the location returned by this call is determined by the permission setting you put in your app manifest, as described in the Specify App Permissions section of this document.

So if you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>` then you will get fine location.

That said, there is possibility you will not get location, because there is no *last location* for the user (it was retrieved long time ago, for example).

> The getLastLocation() method returns a Location object (...). The location object returned may be null in rare cases when the location is not available.

Then you would just need to start tracking user location, as per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html), but after you get first update you can immediately stop tracking and release resources. This will give you location almost for sure (if it's available), but maybe not right away.